# Architecture: Microservices, multiple requirements, and shared data

Tags: architecture, microservices

Scenario:

- We have a moderately large (100K++ loc), microservice-based project, with large, and rapidly evolving content
- we are selling this (both data, and content) to multiple clients, with each clients' requirements being a little different each time, both on data, and content; and they require very high availability on this.
- We'd like to avoid the issue whereby a (code, or data) change done for one client might adversely impact other clients' deployment.
- At the same time, we need to have some of the data (and further changes to that data) shared across clients

Specific solutions we've explored:

- Single deployment, client-specific IF statements:

  - We use this currently, this requires manually juggling which client gets what
  - it is extremely difficult to re-test the entire feature matrix for whether a change might adversely impacts any client
- Multiple deployments: the issue here is 8+ microservices with high dependency on eachother; this would require:

  - setting up a new source repo, and deployment for each client
  - making client-specific changes to that specific client's codebase, deploying to their cluster
  - code, and data infusion between each clients would require reviewing *all data, and code* change for adverse impact

Here I turn to the nice community of Stack overflow: how would you address this in a way that we retain ease of change management, while at the same time avoiding adverse impacts from one client to another?

Comment: Not really seeing how your question relates to Node?

Comment: The project is in node.js; but you're right, the question is language-agnostic. Removed tag.

Answer (score -1):

You can use container based architecture like docker and openshift. Container will provide you service level isolation for each client. If you want enterprise grade architecture, you can use openshift supported by Red hat. For shared access of data across different client and microservices network file system can be used provided by gcp and aws. That provide easy scalability and network security.